# How to retrieve user id from token?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is a `Plan` model that has a user field and I want to fill the user field with user's token so that user can not send user `id` to create the model for another user and just send post request for themself, here is my model:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
"""Plan object"""
user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

and my view is:

```
class PlanViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""A viewset for non-admin user see list and admin can curd plan model"""
model = Plan
queryset = Plan.objects.all().order_by('-id')
serializer_class = serializers.PlanSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

def get_queryset(self):
    """retrieve plan just for its own user who is authenticated already"""
    return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

How to create `Plan` just for user without getting `user` field by request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is **perform_create** method:

```
class PlanViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """A viewset for non-admin user see list and admin can curd plan model"""
    model = Plan
    queryset = Plan.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = serializers.PlanSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """retrieve plan just for its own user who is authenticated already"""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: this self.request.user is obtained by token?

Comment: its ```TokenAuthentication```'s job to get user by token